# How are these two question different to warrant a downvote in one and upvote in another?

Tags: discussion

[What verb could I use to mean "make less anxious"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93542/what-is-a-verb-to-make-less-anxious)

[Specific verb for "training an apprentice"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93756/specific-verb-for-training-an-apprentice)

I posted the first question and then I got downvoted 2 times because it is "a thesaurus question". As I am coming back to mark one of the answers, I stumbled upon the second question which had exactly the same question form. But I notice that question got 2 upvotes instead.

I am not complaining. I just want to understand the difference so that I know how to better phrase my question in the future. Kindly advise. Thank you.

Comment: As inconceivable as it may appear, there is no substantial supporting evidence to explain the reasons because there is no rational connection between the questions you cited.  On the other hand, I noticed that there is a trend toward great reactivity as one votes up a question. In other words, after the first up vote, other users vote up more simply. So, I suppose this phenomenon could be happened for those questions.

Comment: @Carlo_R. So that's a system failure, needs action?